# Ошибка при удалении объекта

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, recyclerview.adapter

У меня есть RecyclerView в который поступают данные из phpMyAdmin, я хочу сделать чтобы у каждого элемента была кнопка - "удалить". Для этого я написал такой вот код в моём Adapter.

```
holder.delete.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            int position = holder.getAdapterPosition();

            String url = "DELETE.php";
            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                    response -> Toast.makeText(context, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(),
                    error -> Log.e("AAAAAAAAA", String.valueOf(error)) ) {
                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getParams() {
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();

                    params.put("position", models.get(position).getPosition());

                    return params;
                }
            };

            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
            requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

            models.remove(position);
            notifyItemRemoved(position);
            notifyItemRangeChanged(position, models.size());
        });
```

Но при удалении последнего объекта появляется ошибка

```
NetworkDispatcher.processRequest: Unhandled exception java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 4, Size: 4
```

Позже я заметил, что при удалении предпоследнего объекта удаляется последний и так происходит со всеми объектами в списке, удаляется на одну позицию выше, то есть я удаляю объект 4 а удаляется объект 5.

В логах ругается на вот эту строку `params.put("position", models.get(position).getPosition());`

В интернете я узнал, что прописав `getAdapterPosition()`, проблема должна уйти, но это не сработало, как это исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваша проблема в том, что запрос асинхронный - он выполняется в другом потоке в другое время.
Это значит что нет никакой гарантии, что методы `StringRequest`-а и колбеков выполнятся раньше чем код, следующий по тексту после их обявления. Это и происходит - удаление объекта из модели происходит раньше, чем попытка его оттуда взять.
Что можно сделать:

- получить позицию за пределами тела запроса

```java
holder.delete.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            int position = holder.getAdapterPosition();
            String serverPosition = models.get(position).getPosition();
            String url = "DELETE.php";
            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                    response -> Toast.makeText(context, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(),
                    error -> Log.e("AAAAAAAAA", String.valueOf(error)) ) {
                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getParams() {
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();

                    params.put("position", serverPosition);

                    return params;
                }
            };
```

- перенести удаление объекта и обновление адаптера в колбек. Думаю так будет логичнее - если запрос отвалился и объект на сервере не удалён, то и локально его удалять не следует

```java
holder.delete.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            int position = holder.getAdapterPosition();

            String url = "DELETE.php";
            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                    response -> {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        
                        models.remove(position);
                        notifyItemRemoved(position);
                        notifyItemRangeChanged(position, models.size());
                    },
                    error -> Log.e("AAAAAAAAA", String.valueOf(error)) ) {
                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getParams() {
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();

                    params.put("position", models.get(position).getPosition());

                    return params;
                }
            };

            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
            requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
        });
```